# Tensorflow cifar 10 example memory leak

Tags: memory-leaks, tensorflow

I am new to Tensorflow. I tried to run the cifar10 examples from here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10

I didn't make any changes to the code, I just tried to run it on multiple GPUs. I am trying to use 6 GPUs and I am allocating 10 GB of RAM for my job but after a few minutes my jobs getting failed due to memory limit. Allocating more memory does not help, it just delays the error. I tried for up to 40GB of memory.

Here is more information about my system:

> == cat /etc/issue =============================================== Linux mmmdgx01 4.4.0-45-generic #66~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19
>   15:05:38 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux DGX_OTA_VERSION=2.0.5
>   VERSION="14.04.5 LTS, Trusty Tahr" VERSION_ID="14.04"
>
> == are we in docker ============================================= No
>
> == compiler ===================================================== c++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4 Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software
>   Foundation, Inc. This is free software; see the source for copying
>   conditions.  There is NO warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or
>   FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
>
> == uname -a ===================================================== Linux mmmdgx01 4.4.0-45-generic #66~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 19
>   15:05:38 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
>
> == check pips =================================================== numpy (1.11.1) protobuf (3.2.0) tensorflow (1.1.0rc1)
>
> == check for virtualenv ========================================= False
>
> == tensorflow import ============================================ tf.VERSION = 1.1.0-rc1 tf.GIT_VERSION = v1.1.0-rc1-272-gf77f19b
>   tf.COMPILER_VERSION = v1.1.0-rc1-272-gf77f19b Sanity check: array([1](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/image/cifar10),
>   dtype=int32)
>
> == env ========================================================== LD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   /opt/sw/cuda/8.0/lib64/:/project/DGX/cuda/lib64/:/opt/sw/cuda/8.0/extras/CUPTI/lib64/:/project/DGX/lib
>   DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
>   /project/DGX/torch/install/lib:/project/torch7new/install/lib:
>
> == nvidia-smi =================================================== Fri May 12 15:46:50 2017
>   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | NVIDIA-SMI 375.20                 Driver Version: 375.20
>   |
>   |-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ | GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile
>   Uncorr. ECC | | Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage |
>   GPU-Util  Compute M. |
>   |===============================+======================+======================| |   0  Tesla P100-SXM2...  On   | 0000:06:00.0     Off |
>   0 | | N/A   34C    P0    42W / 300W |      0MiB / 16308MiB |      0%
>   Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ |   1  Tesla P100-SXM2...  On   | 0000:07:00.0     Off |
>   0 | | N/A   32C    P0    32W / 300W |      0MiB / 16308MiB |      0%
>   Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ |   2  Tesla P100-SXM2...  On   | 0000:0A:00.0     Off |
>   0 | | N/A   34C    P0    33W / 300W |      0MiB / 16308MiB |      0%
>   Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ |   3  Tesla P100-SXM2...  On   | 0000:0B:00.0     Off |
>   0 | | N/A   33C    P0    32W / 300W |      0MiB / 16308MiB |      0%
>   Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ |   4  Tesla P100-SXM2...  On   | 0000:85:00.0     Off |
>   0 | | N/A   33C    P0    30W / 300W |      0MiB / 16308MiB |      0%
>   Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ |   5  Tesla P100-SXM2...  On   | 0000:86:00.0     Off |
>   0 | | N/A   33C    P0    33W / 300W |      0MiB / 16308MiB |      0%
>   Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ |   6  Tesla P100-SXM2...  On   | 0000:89:00.0     Off |
>   0 | | N/A   31C    P0    32W / 300W |      0MiB / 16308MiB |      0%
>   Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+ |   7  Tesla P100-SXM2...  On   | 0000:8A:00.0     Off |
>   0 | | N/A   35C    P0    32W / 300W |      0MiB / 16308MiB |      0%
>   Default |
>   +-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
>
> +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+ | Processes:                                                       GPU
>   Memory | |  GPU       PID  Type  Process name
>   Usage      |
>   |=============================================================================| |  No running processes found
>   |
>   +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
>
> == cuda libs  ===================================================

Here is my job submission script:

```
#! /bin/bash
#SBATCH --account=AI
#SBATCH --time=167:00:00
#SBATCH --nodes=1
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=20
#SBATCH -J TFImgNet
#SBATCH -e tf.err
#SBATCH -o tf.log
#SBATCH --mem=10960
#SBATCH --gres=gpu:6
cpath=$(pwd)
cd ~
source .bashrc
cd $cpath
which python
python cifar10_multi_gpu_train.py --num_gpus 6
```

Here is the error:

```
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162709: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:908] DMA: 0 1 2 3 4 5
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162718: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 0:   Y Y Y Y Y N
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162721: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 1:   Y Y Y Y N Y
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162724: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 2:   Y Y Y Y N N
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162727: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 3:   Y Y Y Y N N
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162729: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 4:   Y N N N Y Y
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162732: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:918] 5:   N Y N N Y Y
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162743: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:0) -> (device: 0, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:06:00.0)
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162747: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:1) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:07:00.0)
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162751: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:2) -> (device: 2, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:0a:00.0)
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162754: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:3) -> (device: 3, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:0b:00.0)
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162756: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:4) -> (device: 4, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:85:00.0)
2017-05-12 15:14:07.162759: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:977] Creating TensorFlow device (/gpu:5) -> (device: 5, name: Tesla P100-SXM2-16GB, pci bus id: 0000:86:00.0)
slurmstepd: error: Job 1313520 exceeded memory limit (11240536 > 11223040), being killed
slurmstepd: error: Exceeded job memory limit
slurmstepd: error: *** JOB 1313520 ON mmmdgx01 CANCELLED AT 2017-05-12T15:28:58 ***
```